# Braces around scalar initializer when using array of struct in a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, initialization, list-initialization

I'm trying to make a simple menu. For it, I want to use a struct that is the Menu and contains a struct array of menu items.

Main Menu
 - Programms
 - Settings

The menu items contain some further information like a callback.

```cpp
struct menu_t {
    char* text;
    const uint32_t num;
    const struct menuitem_t *contents[MAX_MENU_CONTENTS];
};

struct menuitem_t {
    char* text;
    uint8_t type;
    void (*callback)(void);
}

static const struct menu_t mainMenu[] = {
    .name = "Main Menu",
    .num = 3,
    .contents = {
        {
        .text = "Programms",
        .type = MENU_SUB,
        .callback = 0,
        },
        {
        .text = "Settings",
        .type = MENU_SUB,
        .callback = 0,
        }
    }
};
```

But I always get the error

> braces around scalar initializer for type 'const menuitem_t*'

Comment: `contents` is an array of pointers.  Are you sure you want that?

Comment: `contents` is an array of pointers to `menuitem_t` not, an array of `menuitem_t`s.

Comment: Not having an array of pointers has thrown me an error, but now it seems to compile without any errors. Thanks

Comment: This looks rather like C than C++ – especially because of the designated initialisers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... when using array of struct in a struct

You don't have an array of struct. You have an array of **pointers** to struct.

To create N objects, you need an array of those objects. For example in this case:

```
static const struct menuitem_t menu_items[MAX_MENU_CONTENTS] {
    {
    .text = "Programms",
    .type = MENU_SUB,
    .callback = 0,
    },
    {
    .text = "Settings",
    .type = MENU_SUB,
    .callback = 0,
    },
};
```

If you don't want to store these objects within the class, you can initialise the pointers to the objects in that array:

```
static const struct menu_t mainMenu[] = {
    .name = "Main Menu",
    .num = 3,
    .contents = {
        menu_items + 0,
        menu_items + 1,
    },
};
```

---

Other issues with your program:

- `menu_t` does not have a member `.name`, but you try to initialise it. Did you mean `.text`?
- Designated initialisers are not part of any released C++ standard yet. They will be introduced in the upcoming C++20.
- `char*` cannot be initialised with a string literal (since C++11; prior to that the conversion was deprecated), because string literals are const in C++. Either change the members to `const char*`, or use mutable char arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll use it like that.
I know that char* cannot be initialized with strings anymore, but I haven't had time to fix it everywhere I will do it at some later point.

Answer (score 0):

If it is indeed a C++17 code then you have many typos.

For example the structure `menu_t` does not contain data member `name`.

Data member `contents` is an array of pointers. However it is not initialized by pointers.

In C++ string literals have types of constant character array. So corresponding pointers in your structures that are initialized by string literals must have the qualifier `const`.

If you are initializing an aggregate then its initializer list must be enclosed in braces.

Below there is a demonstrative program that shows how your structures can be initialized.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

enum { MENU_SUB };
const size_t MAX_MENU_CONTENTS = 2;

struct menuitem_t;

struct menu_t {
    const char * name;
    const uint32_t num;
    const menuitem_t *contents[MAX_MENU_CONTENTS];
};

struct menuitem_t {
    const char *text;
    uint8_t type;
    void (*callback)(void);
};

static const struct menu_t mainMenu[] = 
{
    {
        .name = "Main Menu",
        .num = 3,
        .contents = 
        {
            new menuitem_t 
            {
                .text = "Programms",
                .type = MENU_SUB,
                .callback = nullptr,
            },
            new menuitem_t 
            {
                .text = "Settings",
                .type = MENU_SUB,
                .callback = nullptr,
            }
        }            
    }
};

int main()
{
}
```